# Using pexpect to detect and handle notifications from Bluetooth LE

Tags: python, pexpect

I've been writing a python code to read values on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B received by Bluetooth LE. 
I can read the correct values with:

```
child.sendline("char-read-hnd handle")
child.expect("Characteristic value/descripto: ",timeout=5)
```

What i am trying to do now is to check for notifications at any time, so i have a Thread that searches for the expected pattern "Notification handle=" like this:

```
def run():
  patterns = ['Notification handle=','Indication handle=']
  while True:
    try:
      matched_pattern_index = child.expect(patterns,timeout=1)
      if matched_pattern_index in {0,1}:
        print("Received Notification")
        handleNotification()
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
      pass
```

Now during my main code, i am always doing some child.sendline to check for new values as well as child.expect . The problem is that my Thread call to pexpect.expect above blocks my others pexpect.expect in my code. 
I already tried to do a second child similar to the first one to work inside the Thread but the result is the same.
So anyone has any idea how i can achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem with this is that your background thread will be eating all the input. The tcl version of expect has a `expect_before` command which allows you to give a list of patterns and actions that should be applied before any later `expect` call. You will probably need to implement something like that, without threads. Or open a 2nd independent connection to your BT control stream for your background activity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i open a second connection to my BT with pexpect? Pexpect allows 2 connections at the same time? And if i use your first sugestion, on each expect i should check if some pattern has been corresponded?

Comment: I don't know much about BT, but for example you can run `sudo bluetoothctl` several times and each of them will get the same notifications about changes. You would just need to call `spawn()` twice to get 2 separate connections.

Comment: I tried your way, but it didn't work because the BTle connection comes from a PSOC 4200 BLE device connected to my computer. I could try to change the PSOC configuration but i want to allow just 1 connection at a time. So i can only try the first thing you suggested. I did some research but the information is not much. Could you please explain how the expect_before/after works? On each expect done after the _before/_after i should do an if condition to check the patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of subclassing `pexpect.spawn` and providing an `expect_before(p,c)` method that would save a list of patterns `p` and callback functions `c`, then override `expect(p2)` to prefix the list `p` onto the list `p2` of that call before calling the real `spawn.expect` function.

If the real function then returns a match index `i` that is within the size of the list `p`, we can call function `c[i]` and loop again. When the index is beyond that list, we adjust it to be an index in list `p2` and return from the call.  Here's an approximation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/51622025/5008284
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, pexpect

class Myspawn(pexpect.spawn):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pexpect.spawn.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  def expect_before(self, patterns, callbacks):
    self.eb_pat = patterns
    self.eb_cb = callbacks

  def expect(self, patlist, *args, **kwargs):
    numbefore = len(self.eb_pat)
    while True:
      rc = pexpect.spawn.expect(self, self.eb_pat+patlist, *args, **kwargs)
      if rc>=numbefore:
        break
      self.eb_cb[rc]() # call callback
    return rc-numbefore

def test():
    child = Myspawn("sudo bluetoothctl", logfile=sys.stdout)
    patterns = ['Device FC:A8:9A:..:..:..', 'Device C8:FD:41:..:..:..']
    callbacks = [lambda :handler1(), lambda :handler2()]
    child.expect_before(patterns, callbacks)
    child.sendline('scan on')
    while True:
      child.expect(['[bluetooth].*?#'], timeout=5)
```

Comment: Well i tried your idea and works like a charm. Amazing indeed. Besides helping me with my problem, your code also helped me understanding and improving my own code (I'm kinda newbie on Python). I still have some problems reading the Notifications values with pexpect but i think i can achieve that in the next days. So, once again thank your for your help and your time.